# Are Scala3 enum parameters "public val" fields by default? They appear to be "private val"

Tags: scala, enums, scala-3

Enum parameters appear to be "private val" instead of "public val" by default.

```
enum Planet(radius: Double):
    case Mercury extends Planet(2.4397e6)
    def getRadius() = this.radius // OK when accessed as a private member.
def getRadius(planet:Planet) = planet.radius  // Error: value radius cannot be accessed as a member of planet:Planet
```

The issue can be worked around by specifying "val" or "var". Then the enum parameter becomes public.

```
enum Color(val rgb: Int):
    case Red   extends Color(0xFF0000)
def getRGB(color:Color):Int = color.rgb  // OK. rgb can be accessed
```

Is this the expected behavior? Compiler bug?  (2021.2.443)

Comment: Just like classes, they are merely constructor parameters without `val` (or `val`). Since you need it for your method, it became `private[this]`.

Comment: Only `case class` constructor params are `public val` by default.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rules of Scala 3, it is the expected behaviour that parameters of an `enum` class are private to the `enum` class, this is different to parameters of the individual cases, which are public.

As you mentioned, you can make them public by making the parameter a `val`.

However, it seems that the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-adts-gadts.html#parameters) does not draw attention to this fact.